# Writing Custom Data frames to from pyspark to Azure Event Hub

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, azure-eventhub

Trying to add a custom Pandas data frame to Azure Event Hub. Here is the code:

```
  dic = { 
           'body' : filter_data
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(dic,index=[0])
    df1 = df.astype(str)
    ds = df1 \
        .select('body') \
  .write \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehEventConf) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "output") \
  .save()
```

I am geeting an error like `"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error above `.select('body')` is called on the str object (df1), which is not supported. The function expects a dataframe (sql-like object). Please try df.select('body')..